# How to most efficiently tie a git build version number, to an apk version with eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, git, version-control

I use eclipse to build an android app, and git running locally for version control. Currently I have a value in strings.xml that represents the version number. If i change that number, the very next thing I do is a code commit in git using the same version number in the comment, so that I can tie a specific build to the matching code that generates it. Very manual process.

Larsks comment helped in pointing me in a direction of defining things better. I think what I want is some type of git hook. Something where, if I change a particular version variable, it will automatically add a corresponding tag. Or, if I issue a tag of a specific format "v3.1.4", it will update the version number in code.

I think prior to reading about hooks, I was hoping for something where I could put "ReplaceWithVersion", or some other special code, and on commit git would know automatically to replace that with the current tag/version.

Am I hoping for too much? Is there a feasible way to get that the versions/tags in sync?

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like the precut use for git tags.  After you update strings.xml and commit the change, tag the commit with the version number:

```
git tag 3.14.15
```

You can then use this tag in other git commands to refer to this specific commit.  For example, too see any change you've made since a release:

```
git diff 3.14.15
```

Comment: That is a good solution. But I was hoping for something more automated. Automated in the sense of, instead of me typing in the number in both places, I could type it in once, and it would be picked up somewhere else, or by git if I used a special code in the comments. I thought something like that existed but I can't remember the details

Comment: I think part of the problem is that I'm not entirely clear on what you want to do.  For example, you can use the `commit-msg` or `prepare-commit-msg` hooks to modify your commit messages.  You could use this to insert build versions into commit messages.